# How do I all the registered users on a day report

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table called users where I have two columns: name and created_at. created_at column column is of type datetime and it stores the datetime when this user was created.

I need to know the number of users created for a given date range. Let's say I ask give me user report between 1-nov-2010 and 30-nov-2010 . I need something like this

```
1-nov-2010: 2 
2-nov-2010: 5
```

The problem I am running into is that created_at data has value upto second. How do I check if a created_at date falls within a given date.

Any help in solving this problem is appreciated.

I am using mysql5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select date_format(created_at, '%e-%b-%Y'), count(*)
    from users
    where created_at >= '2010-11-01' and created_at < '2010-12-01'
    group by date(created_at);
```

MySQL lets you do lots of date-ish things even with datetimes.

An alternative if computing the day after the end day is troublesome:

```
    where date(created_at) between '2010-11-01' and '2010-11-30'
```